# Three20 display local html file

Tags: html, ios, three20

I'm trying to display a local html file from a three20 table controller.  The table shows up correctly, but when I select the item, all I get is a blank screen.  If I use an external URL, the page shows correctly.  I haven't tried using UIWebView, but I was wondering if there was an easy way using the Three20 framework.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**: I forgot [that has changed](https://github.com/facebook/three20/commit/c9bfa1e3ef51700f1549a8594f9d4d374949d903) recently...

Assuming you have registered a `TTWebController` in your navigator that way :

```
TTNavigator* navigator = [TTNavigator navigator];
TTURLMap* map = navigator.URLMap;
[map from:@"*" toViewController:[TTWebController class]];
```

You can simply open a local html file that way :

```
NSString *creditsPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"credits" ofType:@"html"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:creditsPath];
TTOpenURL([url description]);
```

Then all you have to to is to add `TTTableLinkedItem` or subclass (almost all of TT*Cell are) to your dataSource with a local file URL like that :

```
NSString *creditsPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"credits" ofType:@"html"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:creditsPath];
TTTableTextItem *item = [TTTableTextItem itemWithText:@"foobar" URL:[url description]];
```

Much simpler that what I wrote before...

**ENDOFEDIT**

Forget whats under, unless you're interested in others solutions... (more complex... or not, see last one)

---

Basically here is how you load content in a `UIWebView` :

```
NSString *creditsPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"credits" ofType:@"html"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:creditsPath];
NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:urlRequest];
```

The `three20` `TTWebController` can take a request in a query :

```
- (id)initWithNavigatorURL:(NSURL*)URL query:(NSDictionary*)query {
  if (self = [self initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil]) {
    NSURLRequest* request = [query objectForKey:@"request"];
    if (nil != request) {
      [self openRequest:request];
    } else {
      [self openURL:URL];
    }
  }
  return self;
}
```

So to open a local html file in a `TTWebController` you could do this :

```
NSString *creditsPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"credits" ofType:@"html"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:creditsPath];
NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[[TTNavigator navigator] openURLAction:
 [[[TTURLAction actionWithURLPath:@"url://to/your/ttwebcontroller"]
   applyQuery:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:ulrRequest
                                          forKey:@"request"]]
  applyAnimated:YES]];
```

Now the last part, to trigger this from a `TTTableViewController`...
You have in your `ViewController` to implement :

```
- (void)didSelectObject:(id)object atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {
  // there you retrieve a *TTTableItem* corresponding to your row
  // and call previous snippet from URL...
  // TTTableItem class has userInfo property you could use:
  TTTableItem *item = (TTTableItem *)object;
  NSString *htmlFile = item.userInfo.
  [self openLocalHtmlFile:htmlFile];
}
```

Hope that helps!
Nothing tested, at all, should not compile or whatsoever, but that is a solution.

That's a solution using basic three20 + iOS features. You could also write a `TTCustomWebController` inheriting from `TTWebController` that would take urls like `@"myapp://openLocalHtml?file=credits"` that's not that hard to do...

...That here is a draft :

```
@interface TTCustomWebController : TTWebController {}
@end

@implementation TTCustomWebController

- (id)initWithFile:(NSString *)name {
  self = [super init];
  if (self) {
    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:name ofType:@"html"];
    NSURL *URL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
    [self openURL:URL];
  }
  return self;
}

@end
```

Then you could simply use `TTTableLinkedItem` in your datasource pointing to these `@"myapp://openLocalHtml?file=credits"`...

Good luck! :)

Comment: Thank you very much!  I'll let you know how it goes!